# count users if all the courses is completed by the user in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `5r63P4FZ_users` and `5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity`, In this table `5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity` all the courses status will be there, here is have user of  `ID` 36, which have assigned 2 courses, its `activity_id` is `105` and `19`, this 2 courses for the user `ID` = `36`, I want to count that user only if both that course is completed means its `activity_status` = `1`, but right now in my table its status is `1` and `0`, It means that user doesn't completed both courses, so i want to to count that user as 0, I have added my query for that but it gives me count 1 instead of 0, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue, here is my table and query

```
5r63P4FZ_users
```

[image]

```
5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity
```

[image]

```
Query : 

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.ID) as total
FROM 5r63P4FZ_users AS u
INNER JOIN 5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity as ua 
ON u.ID = ua.user_id AND ua.activity_status = "1" AND ua.activity_type = 'course'
WHERE u.ID = 36
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 5r63P4FZ_users.user_id FROM
        5r63P4FZ_users INNER JOIN 5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity
        ON 5r63P4FZ_users.user_id = 5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity.user_id
        AND activity_status = 1 and activity_type = 'course'
        WHERE 5r63P4FZ_users.user_id NOT IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM 5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity
                WHERE activity_status = 0 and activity_type = 'course'
            )
    )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    mysql> select * from tab;
+------+------+------+
| uid  | cid  | act  |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |    0 |
|    3 |    2 |    1 |
|    3 |    1 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select uid, min(act) from tab group by uid having min(act) > 0;
+------+----------+
| uid  | min(act) |
+------+----------+
|    2 |        1 |
|    3 |        1 |
+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

uid - user_id, cid - course_id, act - activity

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join the 2 tables.
All the data you want exist in the table `5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity`.
This query:

```
select user_id
from 5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity
where activity_type = 'course'
group by user_id
having sum(activity_status) = count(*)
```

returns all the `user_id`s of the users who have completed all their courses.
If you only want to count them:

```
select count(*) counter from (
  select user_id
  from 5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity
  where activity_type = 'course'
  group by user_id
  having sum(activity_status) = count(*)
) t
```

If you are interested only in `user_id = 36` then you can add a WHERE clause to the above query:

```
where t.user_id = 36
```

or you can use this:

```
select 
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from 5r63P4FZ_2_learndash_user_activity
      where user_id = 36 and activity_type = 'course' and activity_status = 0 
    ) then 0
    else 1
  end counter
```

assuming that `user_id = 36` has at least 1 course.

Comment: It is true that you do not need to join the two tables. I did the join and then did a SELECT COUNT of the join just to make it clear how you would select the user information for all the users who had completed their courses if that information was then wanted.